# Having trouble getting coefplot() to plot two regressions on top of each other

Tags: r

I am trying to use coefplot(), as described in this article: http://www.r-bloggers.com/visualization-of-regression-coefficients-in-r/

However, when I run that exact code, I get only one regression plotted, rather than 3. Here is a screenshot showing the exact code I have run, plus the output plot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezghR.png

I am really not sure what else to do. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After further investigation my earlier answer is shown to be untrue. My viewing of your image was in error. The code in that page throws errors for me. Need to investigate further. Will delete my earlier answer so you question shows up with zero answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for coefplot does not accept an argument for offset anymore. It's not in the documentation and its not in the formals list. You can make a version that does by modifying the code for coefplot:

Type coefplot2 *return* . Copy-paste the function to the command line and precede it with

```
coefplot2 <-  # the rest of the pasted function should follow
```

then add `voffset=0` to the formals list and change this line:

```
arrows(ci1, (1:k), ci2, (1:k), lty = lty[1], lwd = lwd[1], col = col,
```

To this

```
arrows(ci1, (1:k)+voffset, ci2, (1:k)+voffset, lty = lty[1], lwd = lwd[1], col = col,
```

And change the points line to:

```
points(cf , (1:k)+voffset, pch = pch, col = col)
```

Then hit enter and you should have a new coefplot2 function. Then this should work

```
coefplot2(M2, xlim=c(-2, 6) )
par(new=TRUE)    # could not get the add=TRUE argument to work either.
coefplot2(M3, col="blue", xlim=c(-2, 6), voffset=0.4)
par(new=TRUE)
coefplot2(M1, col="red", xlim=c(-2, 6) , voffset=0.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will point out that `coefplot2` (my extension of `coefplot` which has some nice features but still needs more work), available from R-forge, does this:

```
library(coefplot2)
coefplot2(list(M2,M1,M3),col=c("black","red","blue"),legend=TRUE)
```